# Accessing receiptData info of a user's previous subscription that was canceled, upgraded or dropped on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, skproduct, skpaymenttransaction

there is a method like the following in the android billing library.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/PurchaseHistoryRecord

1. If there is a subscription available, purchaseToken etc. for that subscription. returns data.
2. If there is no current subscription but the user has a previous subscription and for example canceled, the purchaseToken of this old subscription, etc. returns data.

For my **iOS** **application**, I would like to receive the receiptData information of this subscription if the user has a previously canceled subscription or a subscription canceled by subscription upgrade, downgrade. Is something like this possible? How can I access that.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the application receipt located in a file stored at `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL` will have all purchases, past and present.

You can parse this yourself but in order to be sure you have the latest receipt data you should send that data to your server, have that ask Apple for receipt data based on the receipt data you sent, then you'll get back parsed JSON which you can example for past purchases.